# Openliberty arquillian testing

Tags: junit4, jboss-arquillian, open-liberty

I'm running into an issue when running an integration test with arquillian against openliberty. Basically it is timing out on the deployment. Apparently you can set `appDeployTimeout` which I have done. However it does not appear to be loaded as it times out at the same time.

Am I missing something? Can I set this in `server.xml`?

EDIT 1: Logging:

```
[INFO] Running za.co.nb.offermanagement.apis.resources.RecalculateOfferIT
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dcom.ibm.ws.logging.console.log.level=INFO -Dsystem.context.root=/weboffer
Launching defaultServer (Open Liberty 21.0.0.11/wlp-1.0.58.cl211120211019-1900) on OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, version 1.8.0_312-b07 (en_ZA)
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0001I: The server defaultServer has been launched.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKG0093A: Processing configuration drop-ins resource: C:\Users\cc327150\dev\projects\nedbank\bpmexjee-offermanagement\WebOfferManagement\target\liberty\wlp\usr\servers\defaultServer\configDropins\overrides\liberty-plugin-variable-config.xml
[INFO    ] CWWKE0002I: The kernel started after 3.386 seconds
[INFO    ] CWWKF0007I: Feature update started.
[INFO    ] Aries Blueprint packages not available. So namespaces will not be registered
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0058I: Monitoring dropins for applications.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKI0001I: The CORBA name server is now available at corbaloc:iiop:localhost:2809/NameService.
[WARNING ] CWWKZ0014W: The application weboffer could not be started as it could not be found at location weboffer.war.
[INFO    ] CWWKO0219I: TCP Channel defaultHttpEndpoint has been started and is now listening for requests on host *  (IPv6) port 9080.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0012I: The server installed the following features: [ejb-3.2, ejbHome-3.2, ejbLite-3.2, ejbPersistentTimer-3.2, ejbRemote-3.2, jaxrs-2.1, jaxrsClient-2.1, jca-1.7, jdbc-4.1, jndi-1.0, jsonp-1.1, localConnector-1.0, mdb-3.2, servlet-4.0].
[INFO    ] CWWKF0008I: Feature update completed in 8.636 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0011I: The defaultServer server is ready to run a smarter planet. The defaultServer server started in 12.014 seconds.
[ERROR   ] CWWKZ0013E: It is not possible to start two applications called weboffer.
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:17 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: Listing all apps...
[INFO    ] SESN8501I: The session manager did not find a persistent storage location; HttpSession objects will be stored in the local application server's memory.
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:17 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: Size of results: 43
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:17 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: java.lang:type=MemoryPool,name=Metaspace
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:17 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: java.lang:type=MemoryPool,name=PS Old Gen
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:17 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: java.lang:type=Runtime
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:17 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: osgi.core:service=permissionadmin,version=1.2,framework=org.eclipse.osgi,uuid=1e536b3a-5a70-420e-b7f2-a0d1a4d1bb51
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:17 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: WebSphere:name=com.ibm.websphere.config.mbeans.FeatureListMBean
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:17 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,name=PS Scavenge
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:17 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: java.lang:type=Threading
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:17 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: WebSphere:name=com.ibm.websphere.runtime.update.RuntimeUpdateNotificationMBean
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:17 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: java.lang:type=MemoryPool,name=PS Eden Space
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:17 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: java.nio:type=BufferPool,name=mapped
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:17 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: jdk.management.jfr:type=FlightRecorder
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:17 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: WebSphere:name=com.ibm.ws.jmx.mbeans.sessionManagerMBean
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:17 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: java.lang:type=MemoryPool,name=Compressed Class Space
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:17 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: WebSphere:name=com.ibm.ws.config.serverSchemaGenerator
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:17 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: WebSphere:feature=kernel,name=ServerInfo
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:17 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: java.lang:type=MemoryPool,name=PS Survivor Space
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:17 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: java.util.logging:type=Logging
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:17 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: osgi.compendium:service=cm,version=1.3,framework=org.eclipse.osgi,uuid=1e536b3a-5a70-420e-b7f2-a0d1a4d1bb51
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:17 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: osgi.core:type=bundleState,version=1.7,framework=org.eclipse.osgi,uuid=1e536b3a-5a70-420e-b7f2-a0d1a4d1bb51
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:17 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: osgi.core:type=packageState,version=1.5,framework=org.eclipse.osgi,uuid=1e536b3a-5a70-420e-b7f2-a0d1a4d1bb51
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:17 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: java.lang:type=Compilation
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:17 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: WebSphere:name=com.ibm.ws.jmx.mbeans.generatePluginConfig
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:17 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: java.lang:type=OperatingSystem
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:17 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: WebSphere:feature=PluginUtility,name=PluginConfigRequester
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:17 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: JMImplementation:type=MBeanServerDelegate
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:17 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: java.lang:type=MemoryManager,name=Metaspace Manager
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:17 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: WebSphere:feature=channelfw,type=endpoint,name=defaultHttpEndpoint
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:17 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: java.lang:type=ClassLoading
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:17 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: com.sun.management:type=HotSpotDiagnostic
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:17 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: WebSphere:name=com.ibm.websphere.config.mbeans.ServerXMLConfigurationMBean
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:17 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: java.lang:type=MemoryManager,name=CodeCacheManager
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:17 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: WebSphere:feature=ejbPersistentTimer,type=EJBPersistentTimerService,name=EJBPersistentTimerService
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:17 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: java.lang:type=MemoryPool,name=Code Cache
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:17 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: osgi.core:type=framework,version=1.7,framework=org.eclipse.osgi,uuid=1e536b3a-5a70-420e-b7f2-a0d1a4d1bb51
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:17 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: WebSphere:feature=persistence,type=DDLGenerationMBean,name=DDLGenerationMBean
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:17 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: java.nio:type=BufferPool,name=direct
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:17 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: osgi.core:type=serviceState,version=1.7,framework=org.eclipse.osgi,uuid=1e536b3a-5a70-420e-b7f2-a0d1a4d1bb51
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:17 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: WebSphere:service=com.ibm.websphere.application.ApplicationMBean,name=weboffer
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:17 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: WebSphere:feature=kernel,name=ServerEndpointControl
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:17 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,name=PS MarkSweep
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:17 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: com.sun.management:type=DiagnosticCommand
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:17 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: WebSphere:service=com.ibm.ws.kernel.filemonitor.FileNotificationMBean
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:17 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: java.lang:type=Memory
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:20 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: Listing all apps...
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:20 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: Size of results: 43
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:20 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: java.lang:type=MemoryPool,name=Metaspace
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:20 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: java.lang:type=MemoryPool,name=PS Old Gen
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:20 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: java.lang:type=Runtime
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:20 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: osgi.core:service=permissionadmin,version=1.2,framework=org.eclipse.osgi,uuid=1e536b3a-5a70-420e-b7f2-a0d1a4d1bb51
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:20 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: WebSphere:name=com.ibm.websphere.config.mbeans.FeatureListMBean
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:20 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,name=PS Scavenge
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:20 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: java.lang:type=Threading
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:20 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: WebSphere:name=com.ibm.websphere.runtime.update.RuntimeUpdateNotificationMBean
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:20 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: java.lang:type=MemoryPool,name=PS Eden Space
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:20 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: java.nio:type=BufferPool,name=mapped
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:20 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: jdk.management.jfr:type=FlightRecorder
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:20 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: WebSphere:name=com.ibm.ws.jmx.mbeans.sessionManagerMBean
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:20 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: java.lang:type=MemoryPool,name=Compressed Class Space
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:20 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: WebSphere:name=com.ibm.ws.config.serverSchemaGenerator
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:20 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: WebSphere:feature=kernel,name=ServerInfo
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:20 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: java.lang:type=MemoryPool,name=PS Survivor Space
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:20 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: java.util.logging:type=Logging
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:20 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: osgi.compendium:service=cm,version=1.3,framework=org.eclipse.osgi,uuid=1e536b3a-5a70-420e-b7f2-a0d1a4d1bb51
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:20 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: osgi.core:type=bundleState,version=1.7,framework=org.eclipse.osgi,uuid=1e536b3a-5a70-420e-b7f2-a0d1a4d1bb51
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:20 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: osgi.core:type=packageState,version=1.5,framework=org.eclipse.osgi,uuid=1e536b3a-5a70-420e-b7f2-a0d1a4d1bb51
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:20 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: java.lang:type=Compilation
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:20 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: WebSphere:name=com.ibm.ws.jmx.mbeans.generatePluginConfig
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:20 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: java.lang:type=OperatingSystem
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:20 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: WebSphere:feature=PluginUtility,name=PluginConfigRequester
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:20 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: JMImplementation:type=MBeanServerDelegate
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:20 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: java.lang:type=MemoryManager,name=Metaspace Manager
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:20 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: WebSphere:feature=channelfw,type=endpoint,name=defaultHttpEndpoint
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:20 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: java.lang:type=ClassLoading
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:20 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: com.sun.management:type=HotSpotDiagnostic
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:20 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: WebSphere:name=com.ibm.websphere.config.mbeans.ServerXMLConfigurationMBean
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:20 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: java.lang:type=MemoryManager,name=CodeCacheManager
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:20 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: WebSphere:feature=ejbPersistentTimer,type=EJBPersistentTimerService,name=EJBPersistentTimerService
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:20 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: java.lang:type=MemoryPool,name=Code Cache
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:20 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: osgi.core:type=framework,version=1.7,framework=org.eclipse.osgi,uuid=1e536b3a-5a70-420e-b7f2-a0d1a4d1bb51
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:20 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: WebSphere:feature=persistence,type=DDLGenerationMBean,name=DDLGenerationMBean
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:20 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: java.nio:type=BufferPool,name=direct
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:20 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: osgi.core:type=serviceState,version=1.7,framework=org.eclipse.osgi,uuid=1e536b3a-5a70-420e-b7f2-a0d1a4d1bb51
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:20 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: WebSphere:service=com.ibm.websphere.application.ApplicationMBean,name=weboffer
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:20 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: WebSphere:feature=kernel,name=ServerEndpointControl
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:20 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,name=PS MarkSweep
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:20 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: com.sun.management:type=DiagnosticCommand
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:20 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: WebSphere:service=com.ibm.ws.kernel.filemonitor.FileNotificationMBean
Nov 24, 2021 2:30:20 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainer logAllApps
INFO: java.lang:type=Memory
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 43.261 s <<< FAILURE! - in za.co.nb.offermanagement.apis.resources.RecalculateOfferIT
[ERROR] za.co.nb.offermanagement.apis.resources.RecalculateOfferIT  Time elapsed: 43.257 s  <<< ERROR!
org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.client.container.DeploymentException: Timeout while waiting for "weboffer" ApplicationMBean to reach STARTED. Actual state: STOPPED.

Stopping server defaultServer.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0055I: Server shutdown requested on Wednesday 24 November 2021 at 2:30 PM. The server defaultServer is shutting down.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE1100I: Waiting for up to 30 seconds for the server to quiesce.
[INFO    ] CWWKO0220I: TCP Channel defaultHttpEndpoint has stopped listening for requests on host *  (IPv6) port 9080.
[INFO    ] CWWKE1101I: Server quiesce complete.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKI0002I: The CORBA name server is no longer available at corbaloc:iiop:localhost:2809/NameService.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0036I: The server defaultServer stopped after 43.785 seconds.
Server defaultServer stopped.
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[ERROR] Errors:
[ERROR]   RecalculateOfferIT » Deployment Timeout while waiting for "weboffer" Applicati...
[INFO]
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
```

EDIT 2 `messages.log`:

```
********************************************************************************
product = Open Liberty 21.0.0.11 (wlp-1.0.58.cl211120211019-1900)
wlp.install.dir = C:/Users/cc327150/dev/projects/nedbank/bpmexjee-offermanagement/WebOfferManagement/target/liberty/wlp/
java.home = C:\Users\cc327150\dev\tools\jdk8u312\jre
java.version = 1.8.0_312
java.runtime = OpenJDK Runtime Environment (1.8.0_312-b07)
os = Windows 10 (10.0; amd64) (en_ZA)
process = 18348@V105P10PRA4704
********************************************************************************
[2021/11/25 15:29:37:212 CAT] 00000001 com.ibm.ws.kernel.launch.internal.FrameworkManager           A CWWKE0001I: The server defaultServer has been launched.
[2021/11/25 15:30:01:917 CAT] 00000013 com.ibm.ws.config.xml.internal.ServerXMLConfiguration        A CWWKG0093A: Processing configuration drop-ins resource: C:\Users\cc327150\dev\projects\nedbank\bpmexjee-offermanagement\WebOfferManagement\target\liberty\wlp\usr\servers\defaultServer\configDropins\overrides\liberty-plugin-variable-config.xml
[2021/11/25 15:30:02:520 CAT] 00000001 com.ibm.ws.kernel.launch.internal.FrameworkManager           I CWWKE0002I: The kernel started after 26.211 seconds
[2021/11/25 15:30:03:573 CAT] 0000001c com.ibm.ws.kernel.feature.internal.FeatureManager            I CWWKF0007I: Feature update started.
[2021/11/25 15:30:12:061 CAT] 00000014 .apache.cxf.cxf.core.3.2:1.0.58.cl211120211019-1900(id=149)] I Aries Blueprint packages not available. So namespaces will not be registered
[2021/11/25 15:30:12:781 CAT] 00000013 com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.monitor.DropinMonitor        A CWWKZ0058I: Monitoring dropins for applications.
[2021/11/25 15:30:14:909 CAT] 00000014 com.ibm.ws.transport.iiop.internal.ORBWrapperInternal        A CWWKI0001I: The CORBA name server is now available at corbaloc:iiop:localhost:2809/NameService.
[2021/11/25 15:30:16:598 CAT] 0000001f com.ibm.ws.app.manager.AppMessageHelper                      W CWWKZ0014W: The application weboffer could not be started as it could not be found at location weboffer.war.
[2021/11/25 15:30:16:614 CAT] 0000001c com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.TCPPort                       I CWWKO0219I: TCP Channel defaultHttpEndpoint has been started and is now listening for requests on host *  (IPv6) port 9080.
[2021/11/25 15:30:16:786 CAT] 0000001c com.ibm.ws.kernel.feature.internal.FeatureManager            A CWWKF0012I: The server installed the following features: [ejb-3.2, ejbHome-3.2, ejbLite-3.2, ejbPersistentTimer-3.2, ejbRemote-3.2, jaxrs-2.1, jaxrsClient-2.1, jca-1.7, jdbc-4.1, jndi-1.0, jsonp-1.1, localConnector-1.0, mdb-3.2, servlet-4.0].
[2021/11/25 15:30:16:786 CAT] 0000001c com.ibm.ws.kernel.feature.internal.FeatureManager            I CWWKF0008I: Feature update completed in 14.273 seconds.
[2021/11/25 15:30:16:786 CAT] 0000001c com.ibm.ws.kernel.feature.internal.FeatureManager            A CWWKF0011I: The defaultServer server is ready to run a smarter planet. The defaultServer server started in 40.472 seconds.
[2021/11/25 15:30:17:177 CAT] 0000000f com.ibm.ws.kernel.launch.internal.ServerCommandListener      A CWWKE0055I: Server shutdown requested on Thursday 25 November 2021 at 3:30 PM. The server defaultServer is shutting down.
[2021/11/25 15:30:17:724 CAT] 00000029 com.ibm.ws.runtime.update.internal.RuntimeUpdateManagerImpl  A CWWKE1100I: Waiting for up to 30 seconds for the server to quiesce.
[2021/11/25 15:30:17:756 CAT] 0000001e com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.TCPChannel                    I CWWKO0220I: TCP Channel defaultHttpEndpoint has stopped listening for requests on host *  (IPv6) port 9080.
[2021/11/25 15:30:17:776 CAT] 00000029 com.ibm.ws.runtime.update.internal.RuntimeUpdateManagerImpl  I CWWKE1101I: Server quiesce complete.
[2021/11/25 15:30:17:931 CAT] 00000029 com.ibm.ws.transport.iiop.internal.ORBWrapperInternal        A CWWKI0002I: The CORBA name server is no longer available at corbaloc:iiop:localhost:2809/NameService.
[2021/11/25 15:30:20:081 CAT] 00000001 com.ibm.ws.kernel.launch.internal.FrameworkManager           A CWWKE0036I: The server defaultServer stopped after 43.771 seconds.
```

EDIT 3:

```
<server description="Sample Liberty server">
    <featureManager>
        <feature>jaxrs-2.1</feature>
        <feature>jsonp-1.1</feature>
        <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
        <feature>servlet-4.0</feature>
        <feature>ejb-3.2</feature>
    </featureManager>

    <variable name="default.http.port" defaultValue="9080"/>
    <variable name="default.https.port" defaultValue="9443"/>

    <webApplication location="weboffer.war" contextRoot="/" />
    
    <applicationManager startTimeout="200s" />
    <applicationMonitor updateTrigger="mbean" />

    <httpEndpoint host="*" httpPort="${default.http.port}" 
                  httpsPort="${default.https.port}" id="defaultHttpEndpoint"/>
</server>
```

Comment: > Timeout while waiting for "weboffer" ApplicationMBean to reach STARTED. Actual state: STOPPED.

This error is unusual. Generally applications which fail to start end up in INSTALLED state (at which point we try to extract the failure out of the logs). Applications which take too long to start end up in STARTING state.

Could you check the server messages.log to see if there was an error starting the application?

Comment: I think the key message is: [ERROR   ] CWWKZ0013E: It is not possible to start two applications called weboffer.  

This means that the app is not installed at all. Check your server's dropins directory for a file called weboffer.war (or similar).  Also check your server config (server.xml, etc.) for application configuration elements.  If you are using arquillian, then it will install the app - you should remove the file from the dropins/apps directories and any configuration referencing it in the server config. HTH.

Comment: @Azquelt Please see *EDIT 2* Not much there. I have tried setting logging to trace but I think AUDIT is the most verbose...I think?

Comment: @AndyMcCright looked in the dropin directory and there is no war or anything else. Please see *EDIT 3* for server.xml

Comment: Can you remove this line and try again: <webApplication …

Comment: @AndyMcCright Removed that line. Says the `weboffer.jar` is in the dropins dir. but also see an error: `SRVE0190E: File not found: /offer/89765465`

Comment: @AndyMcCright also I do not see any of the other services IE: EJBTimer etc being loaded in the log output if webapplication element is removed from `server.xml`

Comment: I can't explain the EJBTimer, but the `File not found` is likely occurring because the app is not using context root of "/", but is instead it's default context root of "/weboffer" - so your client URIs that use `/offer/89765465` should instead use `/weboffer/offer/89765465`.  Unfortunately it doesn't look like there is a way to specify a different context root when using the arquillian liberty plugin - but you could suggest that functionality at https://github.com/OpenLiberty/liberty-arquillian/issues

Comment: Usually when you write arquillian tests, you don't manually define the context root. Either your tests run on the server so they don't need to know the context root, or for client tests, arquillian can inject the URL for the application into your test with `@ArquillianResource`. See http://arquillian.org/arquillian-core/#arquillian-resource-injection

Answer (score 0):

Which Jakarta EE version you are using?

I have created some template and projects for Jakarta EE 8 and 9 in the past years.

Check the [Jakarta EE 8 template project](https://github.com/hantsy/jakartaee8-starter-boilerplate) and [Jakarta EE 9 template project](https://github.com/hantsy/jakartaee9-starter-boilerplate), both include Arquillian OpenLiberty managed and remote adapter configuration, note read the related docs for details, links provided in the readme of these projects.

For the arqullian.xml configuration, check [Jakarta EE 9 readme](https://github.com/OpenLiberty/liberty-arquillian/blob/main/liberty-remote/JakartaEE9_README.md).

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<arquillian xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">

    <engine>
        <property name="deploymentExportPath">target/</property>
    </engine>
    
    <container qualifier="liberty-remote">
        <configuration>
            <property name="hostName">localhost</property>
            <property name="serverName">defaultServer</property>
            <property name="username">admin</property>
            <property name="password">admin</property>
            <property name="httpPort">9080</property>
            <property name="httpsPort">9443</property>

            <!-- change appDeployTimeout here -->
            <property name="appDeployTimeout">120</property>
        </configuration>
    </container>
</arquillian>
```

Comment: I've had a look at those projects. I'll add the logging

Comment: JavaEE 7. I applied the xml to arquillian.xml but received the same issue. Is it ok if the `arquillian.xml` resides under `src/test/resources`?